# SPI_Communication on Raspberry

Tags: spi

for two weeks I have been testing the serial communication on my raspbrery pi2 and the microkontroler STM32G4. for the UART communication there is no problem however the SPI communication does not really work. The Rpi transmits the data to 16Mhz, for the clocks I chose mode 2 (cpol: high, cpha: low). By default it is the MSB that is read first. I have the same configuration with the STM32G4. I can get the RPI data on the STM32G4 but I don't have the exact RPI data on the STM32g4. Maybe someone knows the solution.
my code is as follows:

```
import spidev
from time import sleep

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 1600000000
spi.mode = 0b10

def readAdc(channel):
    r = spi.xfer2([1, (8 + int(channel)) <<< 4, 0]) 
    return r
try:
   print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit... ')
   print (' ')
   channel = input('wich channel do you want to read? ')
   while True:
     val = readAdc(channel)
     digital = (((val[1]&15) <<< 8) + val[2]) # Digital value
     voltage = (digital * 3.30)/float(4095)# Convert in Volt
     print (' ')
     print ('| ADC Result | Actual Voltage | ')
     print ('-' * 32)
     print (str(digital), ' ' ', voltage)
     print (' ')
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    spi.close()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: You claim there is a problem with SPI.  To check we would need to see clear photos of the connections between the SPI device and the Pi.  We would also need to know the expected results and the actual results.

Comment: hallo, from my Raspery I send[1,144,0], which I receive on the STM32G4. the data sent by the STM32G4 are not exactly received on RPI.  l send [0,3,123], which is the value  provided by the ADC of the stm32g4. With the digital variable I should have 891([0,3,123]). Instead I have 3389 ([61,61,0]).

Comment: You need to edit all clarifications and extra information into your question.

Comment: To troubleshoot, I would (1) use low speed, 1 MHz or even lower, (2) Mode 1. (3) Loopback test at 16 MHz.

Comment: @ joan  Sorry if I'm not clear enough in my questions. I'm starting to use RPI. and since my SPI communication doesn't work properly I thought there may be other parameters to consider besides the mode, frequency and configuration of the clocks. 
With the line r = spi.xfer2([1, (8 + int(channel)) <<<<<< 4, 0]) I send 3 Byte ([1,144,0]). and I would normally receive 3 Byte from STM32G4 ([0,3,123]). which is not the case . instead I have rather[61,61,0].

Comment: @tlfong01  I've already tried to change the frequency and mode.But that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Carole Ngoumkoua, Ah, then I would test Rpi self loopback, at 1Mhz, and then 16MHz, to compare if 1MHz has less errors, perhaps due to noise, glittering, spikes.  Also use shorter cables, say less than 60cm.

Comment: @Carole Ngoumkoua, And let me see, if (1) STM to Rpi good, (2) Rpi to STM bad, does this mean, looking at Rpi side, MISO wiring good, Rpi MOSI bad? Perhaps you can replace STM by Arduino, and always test at low speed, say 1 MHz. Let me think harder, ... :)

Comment: for wiring I think there is no problem . because I receive correctly on the stm the 3 byte sent by the RPi . For the mode, it is mode 2 which presents less error and for the frequency with 1 Mhz I do not have the exact data on the RPI all the time. I have the impression that with each transfer the data are scshifted

Comment: You data sent from Rpi may have a problem.  To troubleshoot, I usually use test data as simple as possible, say just one byte. Perhaps you might like to try my little loopback program: https://penzu.com/p/8b11a6b1. Just copy, paste, and run the program, no library is needed. I am copying the program from Chinese Windows, so there might be some formatting error, sorry about that.

Comment: You see my v0.2 program uses SPI speed only 100 kHz!  This is to avoid as much noise etc as possible!

Comment: If the "loopback one byte test" OK, then you can comment out the "loopback" function, and uncomment the "repeat send byte" function to repeat send bytes.  You need to set the counter to send less or more bytes.  I usually use a scope to check the waveform.  Bed time for me.  See you tomorrow. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: @CaroleNgoumkoua Not many people will bother to read all the comments to work out what does and does not work.  You should EDIT ALL RELEVANT INFORMATION into your question.  I am now making a point of not answering questions where the needed information is contained in comments.

Comment: Hi. this morning I retested the spi communication between the stm32g4 and the RPI (Without changing anything about the program and configuration). it works without any problem though it didn't work the other day. I don't really know where the error came from but now I have no more problems. thank you for your help